# Mapping a tuple

Tags: scala

Is there a way to map a tuple?

Tried the following but not working

```
(a, b).map(v1,v2 => SomeFunction(v1, v2)
```

Possible alternative is case class

```
      (a, b) match {
          case (Some(v1), Some(v2)) => SomeFunction(a, b)
          case _ => None
        }
```

Wondering if there's other alternative.

Comment: Also, `(a, b).map(v1,v2 => SomeFunction(v1, v2))` seems to imply you don't want a `map` operation at all, rather, you just want to use the elements of the tuple as arguments to a function.

Comment: You're right. I want to pass these as arguments only if it's Some(v1), Some(v2). Trying to make use of map for it.

Comment: That isn't a mapping operation.

Comment: Yep, totally agree. I think pattern matching is more appropriate here. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @NithinChandy Just use them directly? If you have a tuple `(a, b)`, just call `SomeFunction(a, b)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over tuples and then `map()` over the `Iterator` ...

```
(9,'c',true).productIterator.map(???)
```

... but tuples hold elements of differing types so the iterator is `Iterator[Any]` which isn't likely to be useful or safe.